# In unix, how to extract last 60 days files from yesterday

Tags: shell, unix, ksh

I'm able to extract last 60 days files from current date. But I want last 60 days files from yesterday.
Below is the command, I'm using to fetch last 60 days files

```
find . -name $val\* -mtime -60 -print
```

I can pipe the output to another find probably like below

```
find . -name $val\* -mtime -60|find . -name $val\* -mtime 1 -print
```

But that would produce files which was modified exactly one days ago from the list of last 60 days files.

Pls help me how to achieve it.

Comment: It looks like you already have a correct answer.  But it's difficult to tell for sure because your question is unclear.  Could you edit your post to give a clear example, with file names and mtime values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can provide multiple predicates to a single `find` command to filter the
list of files being returned. In this case, combining `-mtime +1` with your
first command will return all the files that have been modified less than 60 days ago and (logical AND is implicit) more than one day ago:

```
find . -name $val\* -mtime -60 -mtime +1 -print
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. I saw in some website that -mtime 1 option retrieves files modified exactly one day ago. So i went with it. Now it's working fine....

Comment: You're welcome @Dhivya Since this answer worked for you, you should [accept it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) by clicking on the check mark to the left.  This marks the question as *answered* and (with upvotes) is the way thanks are expressed on Stack Exchange sites.
Welcome to the Stack Exchange network!

Answer (score 1):

Is this command useful?
`find . -name $val\* \( -mtime -61 -and -not -mtime -1 \) -print`
It will list all last 61 days files but exclude files which were modified in last 24 hours.

Comment: I tied the command by @Anthony and it worked. That -and is not recognised by shell. Anyways thanks

Comment: @Dhivya didn't say which type of Unix he/she is using. The `-and` predicate is a GNU extension so won't work with [POSIX-compatible versions of `find`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html). There’s no need for it as find expressions are implicitly combined with a logical AND. For the same reason, the parentheses aren’t required. Other than that, it’s a good answer so I’ll upvote it. Welcome to the Stack Exchange network!

Comment: I'm  new to unix. So not much knowledge on GNU and POSIX. I'm learning through this site... And you answerers are really of great help. Thanking you Anthony and @Nguyen once again....